# Parse the .plist items

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

When i'm trying to parse something strange happends.

I'm counting my items with

```
NSString *bundlePathofPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Mything" ofType:@"plist"];

     NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:bundlePathofPlist];

        NSArray *dataFromPlist = [dict valueForKey:@"some"];

      NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i =0;i<[dataFromPlist count];i++)
    {
        //NSLog(@"%@",[dataFromPlist objectAtIndex:i]);
        [data addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[dataFromPlist count]]];
    }
    [self setTableData:data];

        NSLog(@"%@", tableData);
```

And then:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [tableData count];
}
```

This works great but then in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`

i tried

```
NSString *bundlePathofPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Mything" ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:bundlePathofPlist];

NSArray *dataFromPlist = [dict valueForKey:@"some"];


NSLog(@"%@", dataFromPlist);

cell.Data.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dataFromPlist];

return cell;
```

But the output is:

```
2012-08-13 23:08:48.130 [30278:707] (
    Yeah,
    Trol,
   LOL,

)
```

And in my tablecell it also displays as

```
(
        Yeah,
        Trol,
       LOL,

    )
```

Comment: `(
        Yeah,
        Trol,
       LOL,

    )` in one cell it need to display each in one cell @H2CO3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you got

```
( yeah, trol, lol )
```

...in one cell, right? Now, that's natural. If you had read `NSLog's` or `NSString's` documentation, you would have found out that the `%@` format specifier calls an object's description method - which, in turn, for an `NSArray` object, is a pretty parenthesized, comma separated list of... again, the descriptions of its objects.

What you probably want is

```
cell.Data.text = [dataFromPlist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: @Daniel trust me, parenthesized is fine (and anyway I prefer US English when talking about IT).

Comment: Hair opinion. Being from the UK it's just something I always correct, wouldn't have done if the code formatting was there though.

Comment: Damn, there's me being all "let's spell correctly" and I say "Hair opinion" instead of "Fair opinion"

Comment: @Daniel I just moderated a suggested edit whose author claimed having 'fixed grammer'...